# find specific characters in xml and replace value with that character in python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

find specific characters in xml and replace value with that character in python.I want to find RESPONSE_WM in xml and replace with the character I got.
How can i replace specific path.
I want to my output first RESPONSE_WM change to ABCS_ACME_OPERATIONS_WS_BS_WM
and second RESPONSE_WM change to ABCS_ACME_OPERATIONS_WS_BS_WM.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = """<cus:Customizations xmlns:cus="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/customizations" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xt="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/xmltypes">
    <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:EnvValueActionsCustomizationType">
        <cus:description/>
        <cus:owners>
            <xt:owner>
                <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
                <xt:path>ABCS_ACME_OPERATIONS/business/ABCS_ACME_OPERATIONS_WS_BS</xt:path>
            </xt:owner>
        </cus:owners>
        <cus:actions>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>Work Manager</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">RESPONSE_WM</xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
        </cus:actions>
    </cus:customization>
        <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:EnvValueActionsCustomizationType">
        <cus:description/>
        <cus:owners>
            <xt:owner>
                <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
                <xt:path>ABCS_DSF_RESOURCE_OPERATIONS/business/ABCS_DSF_CHECK_SIM_CHANGE_DB_BS</xt:path>
            </xt:owner>
        </cus:owners>
        <cus:actions>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>Service Operational Settings</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:value>
                    <oper:operations enabled="true" xmlns:con="http://xmlns.oracle.com/servicebus/business/config" xmlns:oper="http://xmlns.oracle.com/servicebus/business/operations">
                        <oper:throttling/>
                        <oper:sla-alerting enabled="false" level="normal"/>
                        <oper:resultCachingEnabled>true</oper:resultCachingEnabled>
                    </oper:operations>
                </xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>Service URI Weight</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:location>0</xt:location>
                <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">0</xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>Service URI</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:location>0</xt:location>
                <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">jca://eis/DB/DSF</xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>Service URI Table</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:value xsi:type="tran:URITableType" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">
                    <tran:tableElement>
                        <tran:URI>jca://eis/DB/DSF</tran:URI>
                        <tran:weight>0</tran:weight>
                    </tran:tableElement>
                </xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>Service Retry Count</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">0</xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>Service Retry Iteration Interval</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">30</xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>Work Manager</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">RESPONSE_WM</xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>JCA Always Use WSDL Flag</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">true</xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>JCA Connection Mode</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">managed</xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
            <xt:replace>
                <xt:envValueType>JCA Overwrite Connection Authentication Flag</xt:envValueType>
                <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">false</xt:value>
            </xt:replace>
        </cus:actions>
    </cus:customization>
</cus:Customizations>
"""
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
namespaces = {'cus': 'http://www.bea.com/wli/config/customizations','xt': 'http://www.bea.com/wli/config/xmltypes'}
customizations = ET.fromstring(data)
strings = []
strings2 = []
counter = 0
for A in customizations.findall("cus:customization/cus:actions/xt:replace/[xt:envValueType='Work Manager'][xt:value='RESPONSE_WM']/.../.../cus:owners/xt:owner/[xt:type='BusinessService']/xt:path",namespaces):
        strings.append(A.text)
C = 0
for servicename in strings:
    servicename=strings[C]
    C = C+1
    D=(servicename.split("/business/", 1)[1] + '_WM')
    strings2.append(D)
print(strings2)


from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(data)
F = 0
ns = {"xt":"http://www.bea.com/wli/config/xmltypes"}
for new_str in strings2:
   
   new_str = strings2[F]
   print(new_str)
   target = doc.xpath('//xt:owner[xt:type="BusinessService"]//xt:replace[xt:envValueType="Work Manager"]/xt:value',namespaces=ns)
   target[0].text=new_str
   F=F+1
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

The error I get is as follows.

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "wm_replace4.py", line 140, in <module> target[F].text=new_str IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: `customizations.findall('cus:customization/cus:actions/xt:replace', namespaces)` is empty string. This is leading to this output.

Comment: try to use regex for the namespace when you use iter() the tree it will give an output like`{http//:}tag`. regex will remove the namespace and then you will get an output you want. In my case, I am removing it using `re.match(r'{.*}', root.tag).group(0)` .

Comment: Can you edit your question and show what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: hi I have update now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to address this - here's one. Since the question is also tagged "lxml", I used that instead of elementtree:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(data)

new_str = "CHANGE_DB_WM"
ns = {"xt":"http://****"}

target = doc.xpath('//xt:replace/xt:value',namespaces=ns)
target[0].text=new_str
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output is your expected output.

Comment: Hi I got this error message ;
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wm_replace4.py", line 25, in <module>
    target = doc.xpath('//xt:replace/xt:value',namespaces)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1468, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:46634)
TypeError: xpath() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)

Comment: @Emrahall You have a typo in there: `doc.xpath('//xt:replace/xt:value',namespaces)`. Copy the definition of `target` exactly as it is in the answer (`namespaces=ns`).

Comment: hi jack ı update my code :) Actually, these are all I want.

Comment: @Emrahall Good to here. If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer please.

Comment: Hi jack thanks for your attention. But I got some other question. I want to change all response_wm with value below the BusinessServices.                          RESPONSE_WM -> ABCS_ACME_OPERATIONS_WS_BS_WM and second RESPONSE_WM -> ABCS_ACME_OPERATIONS_WS_BS_WM

Comment: ı resolved as follow thanks for your answers.
   target = doc.xpath('//xt:replace[xt:value="RESPONSE_WM"]/xt:value',namespaces=ns)
   target[F].text=new_str